# Gotta Collect 'Em All

Tags: code-golf, parsing

Your task here will be to write a very dumb AI capable of fetching all treasures on a map.

### Map

The map is defined as follow: (`artist-mode`™-powered)

Basic case:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|P| | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |T| | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |M|M|M|T| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | |T| | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

---

Locked up:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|P| | | | |M| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | |M| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |T| | |M| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

---

No treasures

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|P| | |M|M|M| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | |M|M|M|M|M|M|M| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |M| | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |M|M|M|M| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

---

No way to move

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|P|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

---

The world is a giant treasure

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|P|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

---

Back alley

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|P| | | | | | | | | | | |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | |M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

---

1x1

```
+-+
|P|
+-+
```

### Cells

- Empty cases are empty
- `M` cells are mountains and cannot be walked on.
- `T` cells are treasures that need to be collected.

### Goal

- You will generate a "path string" describing the movements needed to obtain all the treasures. No extraneous moves after treasures were all collected are allowed.
- Moves can be: "Left" "Right" "Up" "Down".
- Generating a move that'd result in an attempt to clib a mountain (M) or hit a wall (Out Of Bounds) is an error (it's not simply ignored).

### General Rules

- **Map must be read.** (this is not a [compression](/questions/tagged/compression) challenge, there are an infinite possible number of maps).
- There will always be one and only one player, P.
- There will always be a path to go get all the treasures, T.
- Map size may vary, but it'll always be at least `1x1`.
- The AI starts at P, the player.
- There might not be a treasure on the map. In this case, you're allowed to exit any falsy value (that isn't a valid path)
- Your algorithm pick -- it needn't be the most efficient.
- You must solve it before the heat death of the universe
- It is not guaranteed you'll be able to access every non-mountain cell on the map. Just enough to fetch all treasures.
- The AI may see the whole map.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Format

#### Input

- You can decide to take inputs as a multi-line string with or without the ASCII separators I included (same for the space between cells)
- Passed via stdio or a function argument or on your program's stack(s)
- You can other identifiers instead of " ",M,P -- so long they are uniquely identifiable and not a separator (you need it specified in your answer)
- You can decide to take an 2-dimensional array, or matrix, or the equivalent in your language, with the cells, as `[['P', ' ', ' '...], [...], [' ', ' ', 'T'...]...]`.
- You are also allowed to take an array of strings, such as `["P  ...", ..., "  T..."...]`.
- You are allowed to take the length as an extra input (width/height).

#### Output

- The output must look like "LLRRUUDD" (Left/Left/Right/Right/Up/Up/Down/Down)
- You can decide to intersperse spaces, newlines, etc, so long they don't mix with your instructions.
- You can other identifiers instead of L,R,U,D -- so long they are uniquely identifiable and not a separator (you need it specified in your answer)
- There might be different solutions (i.e. `DR` vs `RD`), it doesn't matter which you output in this case.

### Scoring

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge.

Comment: Is the `parsing` tag really suitable if we're allowed to take input as a matrix? Also, allowing input as a matrix seems to conflict with _**Map must be parsed**_.

Comment: Feel free to edit tags.

Comment: @Arnauld Added "back alley", which should answer your question.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/109477/52210)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Though the winning criteria is the opposite :)

Comment: @Ven I know. In my challenge the most optimal path has to be found from the entrance to the exit. In yours any one valid path should be output from the starting point through all treasures. I just added it as a related challenge for people to draw inspiration from, since both challenges require the path to be output and have backtracking involved. :)

Comment: Does the output path end when the last treasure is picked up?  If so, the output of "No treasures" is an empty string (or empty array), yes?

Comment: Indeed, it's an empty string or an empty array. I see no point disallowing "any falsy value", even.

Comment: Pretend there is a mountain on the right of the player. Are we allowed to output `R`, and let the player just stay in place? Also, can we take input as a string with an additional parameter as length of line?

Comment: @Embodiment of Ignorance `Generating a move that'd result in an attempt to clib a mountain (M) or hit a wall (Out Of Bounds) is an error (it's not simply ignored).` (so no for the former), yes for the latter: you may take length in input

Comment: So, uh, we're *allowed* to output a falsey value if there are no treasures? Not required to? But judging from the comments here, then if there are no treasures, we are to return an empty string? So superfluous move commands after last treasure is found is disallowed? But not superfluous moves before that?

Comment: @gastropner my point was: I don't see a reason to force a particular falsey value (like `""` or whatever), any falsey value or "empty" value (say an empty array) is OK.

Comment: @Ven Hm. But it *must* be an "empty" value?

Comment: @gastropner edited: "No extraneous moves after treasures were all collected are allowed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 132 bytes

Saved 16 bytes by having the function ouput `1 0,0 1,¯1 0,0 ¯1` instead of `U,L,D,R`. TIO link below decodes output back to letters.

I may write an explanation later, but most of the work is creating a graph in a format that the dfns [path function](https://dfns.dyalog.com/n_path.htm) likes, then using it to find successive shortest paths between the start and all treasures. Quite efficient, but because treasures are pathed left-to-right, top-to-bottom instead of being based on proximity, the answers are not optimal.

```apl
{z←×`/d←⍴⍵⋄g←z⍴⊂⍬⋄s t m←(⍸∘∊⍵=⊢)¨'PTM'⋄f←{(⍵∊m)∨0=⍺:⍬⋄g[⍺],←⍵}⋄h←(f`⍨,f)⋄⍬≡t⊣{2h`/⍵⊣2h`⌿⍵}x←d⍴⍳z:⍬⋄⊃,/⊃,/2-/¨{⍸x=⍵}¨¨2(g⌂path,)/s,t}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVJBSwJBFL77K@Y2CmubaxkEnupQ0KDodhJBYV09ZAltYC5eLGTbGiki8lpelgg6WBBdgu2fvD9ibzYLV5wliN5hdt6333zve2@m2tpLGsfVvYN6sta2avtGzZhM7A70Lz9uK6qBX@DPwF/g/LSOSUdkbg/4IwKHxCJNBOPAX8EZguMiMQvufcL3aF5nFDkm/rfjQsBxmwlwvOUs8Lf1L4F6CfdlJSjy0kWgIdTMCnBPMROYC9rZnQXuyNYaFVXIuCPcwcW7ONFGuhH4G3emkuCeKGqwaEnV92y01s4Kru/5nhavw0WvVbUaSkI9VKzuxAxqD2Bws53DU/5TGvpXmBULG7jqW9vFiZiBTXd3Ngu0JAzwMdqD/jXwB2w6KRJnuJQVXz7Wyt1YTMyE0DyZCRprijYpWQzqi0DGmC47rss10bdAc0dW68giqXUaM4hJMiSVxkk1Q@7YInm2yN0PGCo2ZbAgftdphFVNblUiz6aVZ2YmGeTf3aUl7ths0NBE/g/Mz7tbkbjTZ@NbKQLM/5oZDYbdrUY9wu8XPX8LoeYj70vKlGmG3WVk7uaJa1NiiqQE7xM)

Comment: Would love an explanation :-).

Answer (score 5):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>385</del> <del>335</del> <del>307</del> <del>270</del> 256 bytes

```php
function c(&$m,$x,$r=-1,$d=0){if($r<0)$r=array_search(P,$m);$m[$r]=V;if(!in_array(T,$m))die;foreach([$r%$x?$r-1:-1,$m[$r-$x]?$r-$x:-1,$m[$r+$x]?$r+$x:-1,$r%$x<$x-1?$r+1:-1]as$o=>$n)if($n>=0&$m[$n]!=M&$m[$n]!=V){echo LUDR[$o];c($m,$x,$n,$o);}echo RDUL[$d];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZBBa8IwFMfP66eI8DYTTLFlt8UobB4VRKqXEiTEuPbQpLw66BA/e9c4kV23eXgk/N7/F95LXdTdZFYXNbGIHndoa4/H0r3ThInu8OHMsfSOGPoEFYeWA8o45bCXCTuVBwo4SVjPNKL@3DVWoynoikPFBFQ5oJJb0ccGpdtdIjQLPbYvrTh4tLpP96lHaGeAcfoSng5aDK2aXY4bGn2j0RUFZwJtnAYWRKUb8HIKjoWx3FQmT8FzaiCXt9uWnawpPFls5uscvBKGXtdyHDwT50t3Pd8sctgrce6i8Zi86qY05E03NoIqJZLk0cNwNeRD8rvqLfIvK/uTtfxR2V0mzO6ylxKRoaT/UU7SZ8JE1H0B)

Uses a recursive depth-first search to crawl the map until all treasures are found.

Input is a one-dimensional array map and number of columns, example: `c( $map, 13 );`.

Output is to `STDOUT` as `L,R,U and D`.

Or **242 bytes** to [output as numbers](https://tio.run/##rZBBa4MwFMfP81Ok8FYTGqmy22IqbOdCD9JLEQkxTg8m8uzAUfrZnelK2XVrD4@EX/6/x3vpm35Ks77piUF0WKLpHR5b@0FjJqb60@pj6yzRdAkdh5EDyijhUMmYndqaAqYxm5lCVF/lYBTqhu44dExAdwAs5F7MsUVry0uE5v6NVa0RtUOj5vSceoYxA4ySV9/aaxGMRXY5bmj1g1ZX5J0UxijxzIuFGsDJDVjmx7IbGS@9Z4uF3N5ue3YyunHghKbXfSwHx8T5gitxnoL1mrypodXkXQ0mgC4hkhyCp3AX8pD8rWaL3GXl/7K2vyp/yIT5Q/YqRKApmX@Uk@SFMBFM3w) (but I prefer the letters).

**Ungolfed**

```php
function c( &$m, $x, $r=-1, $d=0 ) {

    // locate starting room ($r) on first move
    if( $r < 0 )                        
        $r = array_search( 'P', $m );

    // mark square on map ($m) with V to show it has been visited
    $m[ $r ] = 'V';

    // end if no more treasures
    if ( ! in_array( 'T', $m ) )
        exit;

    // generate list of adjacent squares
    $dirs = [
        $r % $x ? $r - 1 : -1,            // Left
        $m[ $r - $x ] ? $r - $x : -1,     // Up
        $m[ $r + $x ] ? $r + $x : -1,     // Down
        $r % $x < $x - 1 ? $r + 1 : -1    // Right
    ];

    // consider valid directions for next move
    foreach ( $dirs as $o => $n )
        // if not a Wall or Mountain and not Visited
        if ( $n >= 0 and $m[ $n ] != 'M' and $m[ $n ] != 'V' ) {
            // display the direction
            echo 'LUDR'[ $o ];
            // and recursively keep crawling
            c( $m, $x, $n, $o );
        }

    // reached a dead end, go back to previous square
    echo 'RDUL'[ $d ];   // display the reverse direction

}
```

[Basic Case](https://tio.run/##rZBBa8IwFMfP66eI8DYTTLFlt8UobB4VRKqXEiTEuPbQpLw66BA/e9c4kV23eXgk/N7/F95LXdTdZFYXNbGIHndoa4/H0r3ThInu8OHMsfSOGPoEFYeWA8o45bCXCTuVBwo4SVjPNKL@3DVWoynoikPFBFQ5oJJb0ccGpdtdIjQLPbYvrTh4tLpP96lHaGeAcfoSng5aDK2aXY4bGn2j0RUFZwJtnAYWRKUb8HIKjoWx3FQmT8FzaiCXt9uWnawpPFls5uscvBKGXtdyHDwT50t3Pd8sctgrce6i8Zi86qY05E03NoIqJZLk0cNwNeRD8rvqLfIvK/uTtfxR2V0mzO6ylxKRoaT/UU7SZ8JE1H0B)

```php
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|P| | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |T| | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |M|M|M|T| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | |T| | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

`DDDDDRUUUUURDDRUURDDRUURDDDLDLLLDRRRRURUUUURDDDDDLRRU`

[Locked Up](https://tio.run/##7Zbfb9owEMefx19xlTxI1KCS0l9aSNG6PuwBT6gKfYkiZCWGRIU4cugaVvVvZ3YaWo/xY6TptIc9HET2fX13H5/jJGGy6HSTMAHKOeNDThPGZ1E81lq6tRjdx/4sYjH4Wh1NDZQZiNtN00CT/DewW/pjNNIQ77R0MUM4J/NhSgn3Q61voKluoakrnBH37FtLeB5E8TD30hw5rQcRtUaMUyIELuIfUdZFvGl@kqsLJW@izOvmfy9Dh89Dh8WQ1HRQ1jTlmBR6JEXMvkSxLjOLL@1WvS6FsXdg49fHW/2R@iGD3uD6xkXMs3ytqDAWixqI6dZT7nBzPei5KPCsp0Xt6AiuSBr58IWktIamJtjg1j40@g2jAfuZUMGbVE4pFVbMqSRDp5K6PEvA9TUQTA0w26BbNUm7x/w7GsAgEbCPt8DGpUrBpWDvVuEV0Lh0hu/TRAJ2jvpYRf2NwUwcxPSey85ur4H9tlLwFvu9R/ffon8ddnsF9gOZw4zBlH2XvE8K3ngHqTX2X/VifYX3icrbCSk8MD4JIEqBwDgi8Uxt99MCv1Oc9T2sclX/L8aqXrXEf6rivyL@HXyeTOhcsD4reWk6f3QE1zfS@xz3amKVr2vJ@kxlbWamgHwuIQvES5dz4bL0@EqDMQVMfsjOv1B2Ayu3Hd5wVyofD0XWeMNr21n/mVH01bp11dj41znlZbAtq5W5HbE2rLQSy9lxicFr5z@zvlhux@In)

```php
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|P| | | | |M| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | |M| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |T| | |M| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M| | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

`DDRUURDD`

[No Treasure:](https://tio.run/##7Zbfb9owEMefx19xlTxI1KCS0l9aSNG6PuwBV6gKfUERshIDUUkcOXQNq/q3U5uG4rEAI02nPezhILLv67v7@BwnHsfzVjsex0A5Z3zAacz4NIhGWkO35sOHyJsGLAJPq6LQQKmBuF03DTRZ/Pp2Q38KhhrirYYuZgjnZDZIKOHeWOsaKNQtFPaFM@KufWcJz4MgGiy8NEdO635ArSHjlAhBH/HPKG0jXje/yNWFktdR6rYXf29Dh69Dh9mQ1LRQWjflmBS6JEHMvkSRLjOLLu1GtSqFkXtg49Xjnf5EvTGDTu/6to@Ya3laVmEkFjUQ063nhcPtda/TR75rPc8rR0dwRZLAg28koRUUmmBDv/Kp1q0ZNdjPhArepXIKqbBiTikZOqXU5VoCrqeBYGqA2QTdqkjaHebdUx96sYB9vAU2LlQKLgR7twqvgcaFM/yYJlrBPlZh3zCYiqOYPHDZ280c3O8rBm@x37t0/036h3EvYDfXYD@SGUwZhOyH5H2S8cY7SOXYf9WbdRXeJypvZ0zhkfGJD0ECBEYBiaZqu59m@J3stO9hpau6fzFW@aol/lMV/xXx7uHrZEJngvVZwWvT@aMjmN9IH3Pcy4lVvK4l6zOVtZmaAvK5hCwQL13OhcvS4zv1RxQw@Sk7/0LZDazcd3jDbal8PmRZ4w2vbSf/QyPrq7x11dj41znlZbAtq7W5HbE2rLQWy9lxicGq819ZXyy3Y/4C)

```php
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|P|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

*(no output)*

[No way to move](https://tio.run/##7Zbfb9owEMefx19xlTxI1KCS0l9aSNG6PuwBT6gKfUERshJDokIcOXQNq/q3MxtC8ViAkabTHvZwENn39d19fI4TB/G81Y6DGCjnjA84jRmfhtFIa@jWfPgYedOQReBpVTQxUGogbtdNA40Xv77d0J/DoYZ4q6GLGcI5mQ0SSrgXaF0DTXQLTfrCGXHXvreE51EYDRZemiOndT@k1pBxSoSgj/hHlLYRr5uf5OpCyesodduLv9eh4@XQcTYkNS2U1k05JoUuSRCzr1Gky8yia7tRrUph5B7ZeP14rz9TL2DQ6d3e9RFzLU/LKozEogZiuvWycLi77XX6yHetl3nl5ARuSBJ68IUktIImJtjQr3yodWtGDQ4zoYI3qZxCKqyYU0qGTil1uZaA62kgmBpgNkG3KpJ2h3kP1IdeLGCf7oCNC5WCC8Her8IboHHhDN@nidawT1XY3xhMxVFMHrns7WYO7rcVg3fY7116@Cb9@7ibG7ifyAymDCbsuyR@lhHHe1jl2H/Vq3WXxBe8z1TeTkDhifGxD2ECBEYhiaZqw59n@J3svB9gpau6fzFW@aoV/nMV/w3xHuDzeExngvVFwYvT@aNDmN9I73Pgy4lVvK4V6wuVtZmaAvKlhCwQr1wuhcvK4yv1RxQw@SE7/0rZDazceHjLfal8QGRZ4y0vbif/UyPrq7x11dj41znlZbArq425PbG2rLQRy9lzjcG685esr1bbMf8J)

```php
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|P|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

*(no output)*

[The world is a giant treasure](https://tio.run/##7Zbfb9owEMefx19xlTxI1KCS0l9aSNG6PuwBT6gKfYkiZCUGokIcObQNq/q3MzsNxWUBRkqnPezhILLv67v7@BwnHsXzVjsexUA5Z7zPacz4NIyGWkO35oP7yJ@GLAJfq6KJgVIDcbtuGmic/QZ2Q38KBxrirYYuZgjnZNZPKOH@SOsaaKJbaOIKZ8Q9@9YSngdh1M@8NEdO60FIrQHjlAiBi/hnlLYRr5tf5OpCyeso9drZ3@vQ4cvQYT4kNS2U1k05JoUeSRCzL1Gky8yiS7tRrUph5B3YePl4qz9Rf8Sg07u@cRHzLF/LK4zEogZiuvWcOdxc9zouCjzreV45OoIrkoQ@fCMJraCJCTa4lU@1bs2owW4mVPAulVNKhRVz9pKhs5e6PEvA9TUQTA0wm6BbFUm7w/w7GkAvFrCPN8DGpUrBpWBvV@EV0Lh0hh/TREvYxyrsHwym4igm91z2drMA9/uKwRvs9y7dfZP@fdzNFdyPZAZTBhP2IImf5MTxFlYF9l/1at03xE9U4s6IwiPj4wDCBAgMQxJN1ZY/zTfAyU/8DrZ3Vfcvxtq/SmxAhv9UxX9F/Dv4Oh7TmWB9VvLqdP7oGBa30scc@f3EKl/XgvWZytpMTQH5XEIWiBcu58Jl4fGdBkMKmPyUnX@h7AZW7jy85sZUPiHyrPGaV7dT/LGR91XRumps/HZOeR1symplbkusNSutxHK2XGSw7PwX1heL7Zj/Ag)

```php
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|P|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

`LLLLLLUURDRURDRURDRURDDDLLLLLLLDDRURDRURDRURDRURUUUURDDDDDLRRUUUUURDDDDDRUUUUU`

[1x1](https://tio.run/##7Zbfb9owEMefx19xlTxI1KCS0l9aSNG6PuwBV6gKfUERshIDUUkcObQNq/q3MztNi0sDjJROe9jDQWTf13f@3DlOPI7nrXY8joFyzviA05jxaRCNtIZuzYd3kTcNWASeVkWhgVIDcbtuGmiS/fp2Q38MhhrirYYuZgjnZDZIKOHeWOsaKNQtFPaFM@KufWMJz70gGmRemiOndT@g1pBxSoSgj/hXlLYRr5vf5OpCyesoddvZ3@vQ/vPQfj4kNS2U1k05JoUuSRCzz1Gky8yic7tRrUph5O7ZePF4oz9Sb8yg07u87iPmWp6W7zASixqI6dZT5nB92ev0ke9aT/PKwQFckCTw4AdJaAWFJtjQr3ypdWtGDbYzoYIPqZxSKqyYs5MMnZ3sy7UEXE8DwdQAswm6VZG0O8y7pT70YgH7cA1sXGoruBTszSq8BBqXzvBzmmgB@1CFfcVgKo5icsdlbzcLcH9sM3iNve/S7Yv07@NuLuF@IDOYMgjZvSR@lBPHG1gV2H/Vq3XfED9SiTtjCg@MT3wIEiAwCkg0VVv@OC@Ak5/4LWznqu5fjLV71aIAx2oBLoh3C98nEzoTtE9KXp7OHx3E4mb6nEO/m1jl97WgfaLSNlNTYD6VmAVk4ZS5nAqXF4@f1B9RwOSX7P4zpR5YuffwiltT@YzI88YrXt9O8QdH3ltF66qx8ds55ZWwLquluQ2xVqy0FMvZcJnBovufWZ@9lGP@Gw)

```php
+-+
|P|
+-+
```

*(no output)*

[Back Alley](https://tio.run/##7Zbfb9owEMefx19xlTxI1KCS0l9aSNG6PuwBT6gKfYkiZCWGRCVx5KQtrOrfzmwaisv4MVI67WEPB5F9X9/5c@c4aZhOW@00TIFyznif05TxPEqGWkO3poP7xM8jloCvVVFsoLGBuF03DTSa/QZ2Q3@KBhrirYYuZgjnZNLPKOF@qHUNFOsWil3hjLhn31rC8yBK@jMvzZHTehBRa8A4JULgIv4ZjduI180vcnWh5HU09tqzv9ehw5ehw2JIalpoXDflmBR6JEPMvkSJLjNLLu1GtSqFiXdg48Xjrf5E/ZBBp3d94yLmWb5W7DARixqI6dbzzOHmutdxUeBZz9PK0RFckSzy4RvJaAXFJtjgVj7VujWjBruZUMG7VE4pFVbM2UuGzl725VkCrq@BYGqA2QTdqkjaHebf0QB6qYB9vAE2LrUVXAr2dhVeAo1LZ/gxTbSAfazC/sEgF0cxu@eyt5srcL9vM3iD/d6luxfp38fdXML9SCaQM4jZgyR@UhDHW1itsP@qV@u@IX6iEndCCo@MjwKIMiAwjEiSqy1/WhTAKU78DrZ3Vfcvxtq/alGAU7UAV8S/g6@jEZ0I2mclL0/njw7i6mb6mEO/n1jl9yVoz1ifqazNsSkgn0vIAvHc5Vy4zD2@02BIAZOfsvcvlGpg5dbDa@5M5SOiyBqveXk7qz83is5ata4aG7@dU14Im7JamtsSa81KS7GcLVcZLHr/hfXFvBzTXw)

`DDDDDRUUUUURDDDDDRUUUUURDDDDDRUUUUURDDDDDRUUUUURRRRRLLLLLDDRRRRRLLLLLDDRRRRR`

[Hedge Maze](https://tio.run/##7Zbfb9owEMefx19xlTxI1KCS0l9aSNG6PuwBT6gKfUERshJDopI4cugKq/q3MztLG5cFGCmd9rCHg8i@r@/8uXOcJEiWnW4SJEA5Z3zEacL4LIwnWku3luP72JuFLAZPq6PIQHMDcbtpGmia/fp2S38MxxrinZYuZgjnZDFKKeFeoPUNFOkWiobCGXHXvrWE50EYjzIvzZHTuh9Sa8w4JUIwRPwjmncRb5qf5OpCyZto7nazv5ehw19Dh/mQ1HTQvGnKMSl0SYqYfYliXWYWX9qtel0KY/fAxsXjrf5IvYBBb3B9M0TMtTwt32EsFjUQ062nzOHmetAbIt@1npa1oyO4ImnowReS0hqKTLBhWPvQ6DeMBuxmQgVvUjmVVFgxZy8ZOnvZl2sJuJ4GgqkBZht0qyZp95h3R30YJAL28QbYuNJWcCXY21V4BTSunOH7NFEB@1iF/Y3BTBzF9J7L3m6X4H7bZvAG@71Ldy/Sv4@7vYL7gSxgxiBi3yXxk5w43sKqxP6rXqz/iviJStwJKDwwPvUhTIHAJCTxTG3507wATn7id7C9q/p/Mdb@VUUBTtUCXBHvDj5Pp3QhaJ9VvDydPzqI5c30Pod@P7Gq76ugfabSNuemwHwuMQvIhdO5cHr2@Ur9CQVMfsj@v1AqgpWbD6@5N5UPiTxzvOYF7pR/cuTdVbauGhu/nlNeCpuyWpnbEmvNSiuxnC3XGRT9X8tYXzwXZPkT) (an original creation)

```php
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|P|M| |T|M| | | |M| |M|M|T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| |M| |M| | |M|T|M|T| | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T| | |M| |M| |T|M|M|M| |M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M| | | |M| |M|M| | | |M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|T| | |M| |M| | | | |M| |M|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|M|M| |T| | |M|M|M|M|M| |T|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

`DDRRUURLDDDDLLRRDRRUULRUURURRDDLDDRRRURRUULLUDRRRUDLDDDDR`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>187 183</s>  173 bytes

Takes input as a matrix of characters. Returns an array of signed integers: **-2** = down, **-1** = right, **1** = left and **2** = up.

```javascript
ff=(m,X,Y,p=[])=>/T/.test(m)?(g=u=>m.some((r,y)=>r.some((c,x)=>(r[o=c=='M'|c>u|(h=X-x)*h+(v=Y-y)*v^c!='P'?0:f(m,x,y,1/X?[...p,h+2*v]:p,r[x]=3-~r[x]),x]=c,o)))?O:g(-~u))``:O=p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VZda9swFH3Pr7h7kpTIytLBHjyUsLK@1WsoHqQIbxWy8tHGlrFsz4bSv56pbUhbaGkanLDBXo6@0NG999x70ZWspFX5Iiu81MR6tZpynNAJvaAZFxHhw37YZ4W2BU7ICM94yYcJsybRGOe0cef5eqVo7VY4F4YrzlGAbtSwvMFzPvFq0p33cMUvvIZ0q5/qA0djNProT91LNW3ooD8ZCcZYRue9o24V@RnNRR3xT97t3UiomytqCCGjM3@GvduSkMtL/4xnqy@iI9CxtAsFSlqNKIgOgAD3AAUEuwJE9IEG2qYJ26EJnkO4P6fCvcWmEzkmgU6NutYxlNkW4gXt@Bm0I977aIIXdAtadOqwib0W77uBItfSlrm2r@rXuqvB2/B61bRefP@4fr9lA4WBxFRP2mewZZhfhi1z/j/NrjB@VPArzBYyLTZl@KhhuGlZu8DGzoPQjP8qaw5Gs9bwWKprkMulbtr5wITv7xNvJOuBu9YerWkxNmv1BvXgqWz3@1GHTU1@ItUcY2EpJBEBPgRlUmuWmi3NDFuWyfgkjfHgM4EeIB8EcqP7FBOWyAzHdxfQt/Nfpz@QiN3JUUTYlVmkGFF0fyNChKz@AA)
(with the output translated back to **L**, **R**, **U**, **D**)

#### How?

This AI:

- Is definitely more artificial than intelligent.
- Rushes like a mad man in the map (i.e. implements a depth-first search).
- Stops as soon as there are no more treasures, but otherwise does not care about the positions of the remaining treasures. This test is done with a regular expression.

  ```javascript
    /T/.test(m)
  ```
- Compares the [quadrance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry#Quadrance) between its current position \$(X,Y)\$ and a new position \$(x,y)\$ with \$1\$ to know whether it can move there. Or tests if the cell contains `"P"` if its position is not yet defined.

  ```javascript
    (h = X - x) * h + (v = Y - y) * v ^ c != 'P'
  ```
- Writes \$4N\$ on a cell that has been visited \$N\$ times and uses this threshold combined with an internal counter \$u\$ to decide -- in a sudden flash of lucidity -- whether it should backtrack over already visited cells when everything else failed.

Comment: +1 for the "_Is definitely more artificial than intelligent._" xD And it may not be intelligent, but based on the run-time it's definitely fast.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 233 bytes

```python
G=input()
e=enumerate
P=T=M=E=frozenset()
for i,k in e(G):
 for j,l in e(k):exec l+'|={(i,j)}'
G={0}
c=-1
while T-G|G&M|G-E-T:
 G-=G;e=list(P)[0];x=c=c+1;r=()
 while x:m=x%5%4;x/=5;r+=m,;e=~-m%2*~-m+e[0],m%2*(m-2)+e[1];G|={e}
print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4xb4MwEIV3/wov1Hax1YCSBetGyxMSA1uVoUIXxQkY5BCVNtC/To244U7fO713N/yM197n62rB@eE5ckEQ0D87DF8jkgpqKMHAJfS/6B@47S99oE7eqfMUuRUFoZtyk@2u3EWBEza0TdkML@7kTSyMWHgdFtKAysj31bVIa2Vn@1bOVhlVxwyrwGqE1j1GXonPw1lP0ECTZjpAPEp311R0MCWn5KinDzjpkEIno@tPdUn@HnuK0Sk34J3KRcTsrG38AxcyBOdHGtaVM1OXhknKKlPW2zRmZxOLiX8)

Very slow. Most of the test cases would probably time out.

`MPTLRUD` → `EMPT1302`. Any other characters should be considered to be prefixes, separators or postfixes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>766</s> 622 bytes

```python
def f(s,W,H):
 Z=enumerate;I=[("L",-1),("R",1),("D",1j),("U",-1j)];o="";P,M,T=map(lambda t:{x+y*1jfor y,l in Z(s)for x,c in Z(l)if c==t},'PMT');E=D={c:{t:0}for t,c in Z(T)}
 while len(E):
  E={}
  for m,N in[(c+d,D[c])for c in D for _,d in I if not c+d in M]:
   if 0<=m.real<W and 0<=m.imag<H:
    T={t:N[t]+1for t in N if not m in D or not t in D[m]}
    if any(T)or not m in D:
     E[m]=T
  for m in E:
   if m in D:
    D[m].update(E[m])
   else:
    D[m]=E[m]
 for m in P:
  if m in D:
   for g in D[m]:
    while D[m][g]:
     for i,d in I:
      if m+d in D and D[m+d][g]<D[m][g]:
       o+=i;m=m+d;break
 return o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJfa9swEH/3pzj0UqnWQsLYSxy9OdDCHMLwKFTzimsrqTNbDrbCGkI@e6aT7KWB6uX8@3Onu5P3R/PW6q@XS6k2sKE9f@IPbB7As1D60KguNyp6FJKS74R/mTFOyQ/CXYxt3OHHT1R2LItaQUi05glPRZPvaZ03r2UOZn56D4/3s92m7eDIa6g0PNOeIXznhYc1qzZQCGHO/G6dpHcsWopYnIr5ycynZ7Sa0ZqycwB/36paQa00XWK3sBQnywIaG76yRkmLsOSxLDJ3kcuNnf7CSwSPYG/UrQHrQ5xkWAfJ6UI0k07l9eIJcl16XDX5dvHgLJAK29VKmiycuc4wfTWWa/xNlkfktFg22dllWk@uj3aEQfZmXxWW1ibScQpUlmNLH31YbXLYl/ZlKKYwZFXdq6sskA@uddYo3ZZBbTs25zP9ThHL7UA5WzUsbKBcIb@z2O3HZoQl5ixucwHaUFRRI6wcvdqF/gmgU@bQaWgvRvWmyHvVgwAZSLImGceQ@EN4ACT5FAy@NEntDU6CBFAZwHAG34huJO7jlUq9Ox2Oc9u4/gi8kgVZELhXHwbAPfwfxk6@7yptKPmlyWTXVppKMiH3s29ZOJpCSX47hrHRvaGjyPGXHoGcZuyGYIxd/gE)

Fairly certain after this that I will never win code-golf, but contributing because I enjoyed the exercise.

This version works by building a dictionary of reachable locations, with each entry being a dictionary whose keys are a unique ID for the treasure, and whose value is the shortest distance to that treasure.  The code supports multiple values for P: for each one it outputs a path that collects the treasures.  No optimization is attempted.. it picks the nearest treasure from its current location until all treasures are collected.

Comment: Can reduce it by 5 bytes by using e=enumerate, and adjusting 1 space after any(T)

Comment: You can often put an `if` statement and the line to execute on the same line e.g. `if any(T)or not m in D:E[m]=T`.